# Add column on Oracle database which store current date/time whenever table row updated

Tags: oracle

Add column on Oracle database which store current date/time whenever table row updated. i did using below alter command but it did not work, it showing null value for UPDATED_DATE.

```
alter table system_notification add UPDATED_DATE date default null;
alter table system_notification modify UPDATED_DATE default sysdate;
```

Comment: It will only be set for new inserted values. Not for existing rows

Comment: oks.. but how to set default time for existing rows during updation.

Comment: An additional update statement  which sets the date for the existing records? BTW. The column will not be changed automaticaly if you update a row. It will only be set at insert

Answer (score 0):

Along with a column, you'll need a database trigger, such as

```
create or replace trigger trg_bu_sysnot
  before update on system_notification
  for each row
begin
  :new.updated_date := sysdate;
end;
/
```

If it should fire on `INSERT` as well, you'd modify it to `before update or insert on ...`.